# ES6/Javascript: How to do an efficient loop to create json objects in array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to create a loop which is going to push this a number of times in an array.

```
{ width: 30 },
{ width: 30 },
{ width: 12 },
```

and after iterating a certain number of times, i want to append the

```
{ width: 30 },
{ width: 30 },
```

at the end. So if we run the loop for two times i want the result in an array like,

```
{ width: 30 },
{ width: 30 },
{ width: 12 },
{ width: 30 },
{ width: 30 },
{ width: 12 },
{ width: 30 },
{ width: 30 },
```

I'm not sure how to do the append part at the end.

Comment: So you would like to push the first two elements of an array?

Comment: No, I want to push these things in a blank array.

Comment: can you provide what you tried ?

Comment: `array.push(object)`

Comment: But do it take a collection of object @JaromandaX

Comment: I mean array.push({a:'1'},{b:'2'},{c:'3'}) like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the array.prototype.push() to append multiple items to the end of an array.

```
    // initialize the array
    var arr = [];
    
    // push the values into the array till the index has reached your defined limit
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr.push({ width: 30 }, { width: 30 }, { width: 12 });
    }

    // append the values to the array after the loop has finished
    arr.push({ width: 30 }, { width: 30 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = [
{ width: 30 },
{ width: 30 },
]

const b = [
{ width: 30 },
{ width: 30 },
{ width: 12 },
]

const c = [...a]
const d = [...c,...b]
const e = [...d,...a]
console.log(e)
```

Comment: It pushes the *same* objects. In case of a mutation, it can have (maybe) undesired side-effects...

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are wanting something like this-

```js
const data = [
  { width: 30 },
  { width: 30 },
  { width: 12 },
];

const suffix = [
  { width: 30 },
  { width: 30 },
];

const generateResult = (iteration, arr, suffixArr) => {
  let res = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {
    res = [...res, ...arr];
  };
  
  res = [...res, ...suffixArr];

  return res;
}

const res = generateResult(2, data, suffix);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: You are providing iteration as 2 right? then there should two first elements but your output says:
[
  {
    /**id:2**/
    "width": 30
  },
  {
    /**id:3**/
    "width": 30
  },
  {
    /**id:4**/
    "width": 12
  },
  /**ref:2**/,
  /**ref:3**/,
  /**ref:4**/,
  {
    "width": 30
  },
  {
    "width": 30
  }
]

Comment: Please run the code elsewhere. There are some identical objects here so the stackOverflow gives it reference.

Comment: Sure. Let me check.